# How can i set certain string as a condition in an if-statement?

Tags: r, if-statement

As mentioned last time: I'm new and I'm trying to make some conditions in order to make functions which work along different strings in a column.
I have a data frame with 4 columns and want to add a new column which is calculated by the following function. If I execute this, I got an error that it doesn't fit, since the column has 113 rows and the result is only 95. 
I want only 95 results and would like to calculate the missing rows with different condition(String: P2).

If you can't see my problem: How can I calculate the non-fitting rows? After using all needed conditions(the different string in that column is 'origin') I want to have a filled column.

```
#badtry 1
originp1x<-function(origin,final_distance,rads,P1X=481073) 
  for ("P1" in Origin) { x<-(sin(rads) * final_distance)
  xp1=(P1X+x)
  return(xp1)
  }

xfinal<-originp1x(dat$origin,dat$final_distance,dat$rads,P1X)
dat$xfinal<-xfinal
```

edit: 
partially working zx8754, but if i only want that for a few rows? -like only for all "P1" in the origin-column?

```
id    origin    final_distance    rads    
1       P1          12             0,2
2       P2          13             0,2
3       P1           7             0,09
4       P4          11             0,08
5       P3           9             0,05
```

Comment: Your function syntax is bad. It needs to be of the form

```tmp <- function(...){
 for (i in origin){
 stuff  
}
stuff
}```

and now my syntax has been lost in the comment :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read on about [vectorisation](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-vectorize-your-functions-in-r.html), try this:

`dat$xfinal <- ifelse(dat$origin=="P1",481073+sin(dat$rads)*dat$final_distance,NA)`

Comment: partially working, but if i only want that for a few rows? -like only for all "P1" in the origin-column? 

    id    origin    final_distance    rads    
    1       P1          12             0,2
    2       P2          13             0,2
    3       P1           7             0,09
    4       P4          11             0,08
    5       P3           9             0,05

Comment: i cannot since i dont have 15 reputation yet.. im sry

Comment: I got it! i now know how to use ifelse in a loop. thanks for your help!